# How to .read the 'file with "," (comma) as a separator, which separates decimal numbers separated by "," (comma)'?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to analyze (reading them in spider / python 3.7) files (.au_reg) which they use as a separator, which however contain some columns with integers and others with decimal numbers separated by comma (0, 0,1, 0,987, 0,789, 1,567 etc .).

Obviously, reading the file using comma as a separator creates a mess, separating each number between commas.

How can I do? 
I thought of replacing the comma with the dot (within decimal numbers), but I don't know how to do it? Are there practical solutions for reading such messy files?

thanks for the help

Comment: The decimal numbers are seperated only by a comma. Check if the other columns are seperate by comma and space/tab.

Comment: You have to find the pattern: a comma and space means a new element a comma and a number is part of the number ...

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is that `comma and a space` separate between the number elements then you can simply do:

```
numbers = '0, 0,1, 0,987, 0,789, 1,567'
list_numbers = numbers.split(', ')
print(list_numbers)
```

result

```
['0', '0,1', '0,987', '0,789', '1,567']
```

or with regular expressions, assuming the elements consist of numbers with or without comma's

```
import re
numbers = '0, 0,1, 0,987, 0,789, 1,567'
numbers += ', '
list_numbers = re.findall('[0-9,]+(?=,\s)', numbers)
print(list_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use a period (`.`) as opposed to a comma (`,`) for a decimal separator, the main reason being that this is the case for most of the standard data formats as well as computer languages.

If it is not possible to change the commas to periods in your data, then another alternative is that if the format of your data contains a space between values (e.g: `0,123, 1.23, 5.61`) then your separator could be a comma and a space (`,` ).