# pandas: Import data from .txt where both the delimiter/separator and decimal are commas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file containing strings, floats and integers. The decimals are commas, as well as the delimiter/separator. The floats can be "normal" but also academic/scientific notation (like 1,92967e-009). The normal floats have four whitespaces in front `(    0,797739)`.

Example row:

```
2,male,    0,879876,    0,120124,7,55166e-010,3,03629e-008,1,06476e-007,3,68805e-019,1
```

Importing in pandas leads to weird results because pandas can't differentiate between delimiter and decimal and adds some more colums that doesn't exist.

I read the manual for `read_csv` and tried it with a regex but couldn't solve the problem.

I also tried the following:
[How to .read the 'file with "," (comma) as a separator, which separates decimal numbers separated by "," (comma)'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096343/how-to-read-the-file-with-comma-as-a-separator-which-separates-decimal)
in combination with a for loop but it doesn't work for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re

path = open("path\Cluster.txt", "r") #extra loading because of a long path with vowel mutation
LCA_data = csv.reader(path)
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=0, sep=',', decimal=',')
df.head()
```

I'm expecting a tabulated dataframe but pandas adds some more colums because it sepates on each comma.

Comment: can you add expected result after the file is being read?

Comment: Hi vb_rises, thanks for asking. I'm new, so unfortunately I'm not able to upload a photo. It will get a little ugly put the actual output looks like 2 male 0 879876 0 120124.000000 7 0.000006 3 0.000036 1 6.476000e-04 3 6.880500e-15 1 and the expected should look like 0 2 male 0.88 0.12 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 1